# how to get three or more 5*5 sub-region at random and assign it to 0 in a high 2-D matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

Now there is a high two-dimensional matrix, such as 500*500, which I would like to get  three or more sub region of 5*5 at random and assign it to 0,any efficient algorithm will be appreciate, Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can assign to slices `a[2:7, 10:15] = numpy.zeros((5,5))`, you just need to randomly generate the locations of those slices

Comment: Could there be overlap in assigning blocks as zeros?

Comment: @CoryKramer  Thanks at first,however, the key point is the random.

Comment: @Divakar No overlap better.